React - Ionic Modals SwiperJS strange behavior, automatically changing active slide(with gif)
Inside one of my ionic page (categories). I have list of multiple swipers. Every swiper slide have item that have some button. On click on that button, modal will show. Modal component is outside of Swiper component (only one modal instance for whole page).
After I close that modal, from time to time, current swiper automatically changes active slide to some other slide (that has been clicked before) (it also calls onSlideChange event, I checked).
Also, when I click on some other swiper slide it will change slide of first/problematic swiper, and it jumps to that changed slide/swiper (scrolls page to it)
And I'm not sure is this problem is with slider, or with Ionic Modals.
I updated both projects to newest versions:
"@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.3.0",
"@ionic/react": "^8.3.1",
"@ionic/react-router": "^8.3.1",
"swiper": "^11.1.14",



Facing this same issue in ionic angular. Is there any solution or work around?

I did some temporary solution, by lock/forcing slider to stay on slide before enter modal, and to wait timeout of 300ms after closing, before you can enable slider again
